# Object initializer + property initializer (from C# to F#)

Tags: class, oop, f#

I have a Person and I want initialize the Name with the property initializer and the Age with the constructor.

**C# version**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person(int age)
    {
        Age = age
    }
}

var person = new Person(20) { Name = "Alex" };
```

I've tried with F#:

**Try 1: Invalid syntax**

```
type Person = {
    Name: string
    Age: int
} with 
    static member create (age: int): Person =
        { this with Age = age }: Person
```

**Try 2: Invalid syntax**

```
type Person =
    member val Name: string
    member val Age: int

    new(age: int)
        this.Age = 13
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
type Person(age:int) =
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val Age = age with get, set

let person = Person(20, Name = "Alex")
```

Comment: To me it doesn't look like the same thing (but then I am not that familiar with C#). Is it the same, or is it 'just' the closest we can get?

Comment: @RobertNielsen It F#'s syntax for the same thing. Why do you want to do this anyway? It's not very idiomatic F#. Why not use a plain record? You would get several advantages from doing so.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox I don't have a preference, I just thought the syntax looked a little peculiar and wanted to ask. Thank you for the answer, now I know.

Comment: @kvb It works, but you are assigning a default value to the properties. I only want assign values with "object initializer + property initializer".

Comment: @JohnDoe C# implicitly provides defaults of `null` and `0`. F# avoids implicit defaults as they're more error-prone. So you can either provide the same defaults as C# would or pick better ones. This is one of the reasons why what you're trying to do is high friction in F#. You should abandon this whole approach unless you have a good reason for it.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Yes, but I thought F# could provide lateinit and other features... and that a type could has multiple (and static) constructors...

Comment: @John Doe, the problem is that the properties need memory backing, so, in this example, even if Name and Age are called properties they are more like instance variable fields.

Comment: @JohnDoe `lateinit` appears to be a Kotlin feature that means you would throw an exception on accessing the uninitialised property, instead of returning a default value. F# does not have this feature, preferring to avoid the possibility of a runtime exception. A `Person` has to have a `Name` and an `Age` before it is a `Person`.

Comment: @JohnDoe - Is there a reason that it *matters* that `Name` is set to a particular value syntactically?  That's a requirement of F#'s auto-prop syntax.  If you use `null : string` instead of `""`, then the behavior will be indistinguishable from your C# class's from a caller's perspective - the property always has a defined value, even in C#, it just defaults to null if you don't specify it explicitly.  Are you actually trying to convert some more complicated example that uses different features?